# Streaming process with different case classes

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement a streaming process on Kafka. The data structure that I'm using looks like this one:

```
trait Base {def baseField: String}
final case class Elem0(baseField: String, oil: String, oil2: String) extends Base
final case class Elem1(baseField: String, engine: String, engine2: String) extends Base
final case class Elem2(baseField: String, tire: String, tire2: String) extends Base
```

This is just a simplification, the real "ElemX" classes (and the Base) have many more fields. The main App receives different objects of each of the classes using different Kafka topics. Each object needs to be processed independently.

I need to implement a function that does some complicated logic depending on the values of the fields of "ElemX". The possible values of "oil", "engine" and "tire" are the same for all classes (let's say that they can be "X", "Y", "Z"). I mean, there are just 3 possible values for all the case classes' fields. So my first approach is something like this:

```
def doSomethingWithElem0(record: Elem0) = {
    if (record.oil == "X") {
        ... // logic1 
    } else if (record.oil == "Y") {
        ... // logic2
    } else {
        ... // logic3
    }

    if (record.oil2 == "X") {
        ... // logic1
    } else if (record.oil2 == "Y") {
        ... // logic2
    } else {
        ... // logic3
    }
    ...
}


def doSomethingWithElem1(record: Elem1) = {
    if (record.engine == "X") {
        ... // logic1
    } else if (record.engine == "Y") {
        ... // logic2
    } else {
        ... // logic3
    }

    if (record.engine2 == "X") {
        ... // logic1
    } else if (record.engine2 == "Y") {
        ... // logic2
    } else {
        ... // logic3
    }
    ...
}


def doSomethingWithElem2(record: Elem2) = {
    if (record.tire == "X") {
        ... // logic1
    } else if (record.tire == "Y") {
        ... // logic2
    } else {
        ... // logic3
    }

    if (record.tire2 == "X") {
        ... // logic1
    } else if (record.tire2 == "Y") {
        ... // logic2
    } else {
        ... // logic3
    }
    ...
}
```

As you can see there is a lot of duplicated logic but it all depends on the values of the case class fields. I cannot have something like this:

```
if (record.tire == "X" || record.tire2 == "X") {
    // logic1
}
```

Because the logic involves doing something with each of the field values. This logic involves checking that specific value on a Redis database and things like checking the last time a certain value was received (for instance, I need to check if the value of `record.tire` was stored previously and do some calculations based on this). The key point is that I want to "apply" the same logic for all the case class fields without having to go over each `record.field`

Is there any way I could simplify this logic? I've been checking libraries like shapeless but I don't know if I can apply this kind of functions here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to apply logic to every field without going over each field? Would need some kind of magic for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, case classes are `Product`s, so if you are talking about iterating over a case class fields, and applying the same logic to them, you could do something like:

```
record.productIterator.tail.foreach { 
    case "X" => logic1()
    case "Y" => logic2()
    case _ => logic3()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dima. I assume there's no way to get the name of the field inside the cases, right?

Comment: In 2.13, there is `productElementNames`, so you can do `record.productElementNames zip record.productIterator` to get pairs. Before 2.13, you'd have to mess with java reflection (like `record.getClass.getDeclaredFields.map(_.getName)` ) to get to the names